# Laravel FileManager - TinyMCE4

Tags: laravel, tinymce

After following all the instructions to install [TinyMCE - FileManager](http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation)
and integrate the code in my blade I found this results.

[image]

What is the problem? 
Must I do some configurations?
I think that the problem is from the upload path.

Comment: That looks like a translation problem, do you have the required language packages?

Comment: I think not...how i said i following the istructions!
Do you have a link with the package and like install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all which language are you using for your app ? Check config/app.php for "locale". If you set language which Unisharp does not support, you should set the fallback_locale to 'en' in config/app.php. My second thought is that you didn't run the publish commands, you can do it like this

```
php artisan vendor:publish // This will publish all assets of every package in vendor folder
```

Comment: Ok thanks, now it's working! If i uploads files doc, pdf it work but if i want upload an image doesn't work, why? Could you teach me why inside the folder files there are two others folders with name 1 and shares?

Comment: Another question, it's possibile to show directly the fileManager page in my blade? I' don't need the editor and textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you using on this app? Then go to the folder below.

> YOUR_APP/vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/lang/WHICH_LANG

And copy the language folder

> YOUR_APP/resources/lang/vendor/laravel-filemanager/LANG

You can read more on [here](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/customization)